# I want to use beamer-latex in Ubuntu. using the Kile version of latex. Compiling frequently responds 'pfgcore.sty missing' what to do?

Tags: 22.04, latex, texlive, kile

I want to use beamer-latex with Kile for Ubuntu. Compiling with pdf-latex or latex responds
with 'pfgcore.sty missing', what should I do?

Comment: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=299509 and probably you're trying to compile a very old version, similar errors where reported some 11 years ago but not much later.

Answer (score 0):

You can install most of the latex packages with `sudo apt install texlive-full`.